# Jquery .on() method not working with $.get() content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code like below:

```
$.get( "includes/ajax_ok.php", { edycja: "<?=$_GET[edycja]; ?>"} ,function( data ) {
    $('#lista').html(data);
});
$("document.body").on('click', '#test' ,function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("ok");
});
<body>    
    <div id="lista"></div>
</body>
```

For test purposes, ajax_ok.php file has only a code line:

```
<a href='' id='test'>x</a>
```

The problem is, when i click an anchor *x* the alert with *ok* message doesn't appear.

I have tried code like below with succeed so I think the reason is $.get() function but I have to do this with it.

```
$('#lista').html("<a href='' id='test'>x</a>");

$("document.body").on('click', '#test' ,function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("ok");
});
```

Maybe someone had the same problem but has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "body", not "document.body", the first arg to jQuery is always a CSS selector or HTMLDOMElement.

You could also use document.body without the quotes.

Comment: I'd suggest binding the event to `document`, rather than `'body'`. Attaching the event to the `document` element is more reliable, since it's always going to be there.

Comment: @JoshCrozier not sure if serious?

Comment: @DavidXu Yes, I'm completely serious. Compare these two examples: http://jsfiddle.net/g31wda48/ ... http://jsfiddle.net/xr165stw/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("document.body")
```

to

```
$("body")
```

The `document` variable is something you use outside strings, when referring to the document.

You *can* also attach the event to the document, if that is what you want:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test' ,function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("ok");
});
```